# NodeJS basic app - 404 error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm following this basic tutorial

https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-role-based-authentication-with-passport-in-ionic-2-part-1/

My problem is that when going on the browser to:

http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/login
http://localhost:8080/register

I get the following on the terminal:

```
App listening on port 8080
GET / 404 5.436 ms - 139
GET /login 404 0.469 ms - 144
GET /register 404 0.451 ms - 147
```

I don't know why because the routes are configured there on the file: `app/routes.js` as follows:

```
var AuthenticationController = require('./controllers/authentication'),
    TodoController = require('./controllers/todos'),
    express = require('express'),
    passportService = require('../config/passport'),
    passport = require('passport');

var requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });

module.exports = function (app) {

    var apiRoutes = express.Router(),
        authRoutes = express.Router(),
        todoRoutes = express.Router();

    // Auth Routes
    apiRoutes.use('/auth', authRoutes);

    authRoutes.post('/register', AuthenticationController.register);
    authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);

    authRoutes.get('/protected', requireAuth, function (req, res) {
        res.send({ content: 'Success' });
    });

    // Todo Routes
    apiRoutes.use('/todos', todoRoutes);

    todoRoutes.get('/', requireAuth, AuthenticationController.roleAuthorization(['reader', 'creator', 'editor']), TodoController.getTodos);
    todoRoutes.post('/', requireAuth, AuthenticationController.roleAuthorization(['creator', 'editor']), TodoController.createTodo);
    todoRoutes.delete('/:todo_id', requireAuth, AuthenticationController.roleAuthorization(['editor']), TodoController.deleteTodo);

    // Set up routes
    app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

}
```

> If you want to try by yourself, here is the repository which includes installation instructions:

https://github.com/zeuscronos/node-ionic-01

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure but because of `app.use('/api', apiRoutes);`, your URL should be `http://localhost:8080/api/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: also tried that with no success. If you want, you can try the project I added on my post above.

Comment: You're listening for POST requests on `/register` and `/login`. You need to define `GET` listeners as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the your code with following snippet

```
var AuthenticationController = require('./controllers/authentication'),
    TodoController = require('./controllers/todos'),
    express = require('express'),
    passportService = require('../config/passport'),
    passport = require('passport');

var requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });

module.exports = function (app) {

var apiRoutes = express.Router(),
    authRoutes = express.Router(),
    todoRoutes = express.Router();

// Auth Routes
authRoutes.post('/register', AuthenticationController.register);
authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);

authRoutes.get('/protected', requireAuth, function (req, res) {
    res.send({ content: 'Success' });
});

apiRoutes.use('/auth', authRoutes);


// Todo Routes

todoRoutes.get('/', requireAuth, AuthenticationController.roleAuthorization(['reader', 'creator', 'editor']), TodoController.getTodos);
todoRoutes.post('/', requireAuth, AuthenticationController.roleAuthorization(['creator', 'editor']), TodoController.createTodo);
todoRoutes.delete('/:todo_id', requireAuth, AuthenticationController.roleAuthorization(['editor']), TodoController.deleteTodo);
apiRoutes.use('/todos', todoRoutes);

// Set up routes
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
}
```

Here you have registered your routes before adding route paths. That's why they are not working as expected. Now you can access the routes as

```
API : /api
AUTH : /api/auth/login || /register
TODOS : /api/todos
```

Comment: Harish, unfortunatelly none of the above 4 url works

Comment: If you want, you can try the project I added on my post above.

Comment: @devidesp I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

The way you've structured your app is not standard. You should define your routers and routes before you start using them (making calls to `app.use()` after you've defined the requests you want to listen for).

If you have different routers, place them in different files.

Here's why things are not working:

http://localhost:8080/ : You don't have any index route

http://localhost:8080/login, http://localhost:8080/register: You have registered these routes as POST routes, so GET requests wont work, secondly they both have a base url of `/auth` so the only way you'll be able to use them is by accessing `/auth/login` and `/auth/register`

Define two additional request listeners

```
authRoutes.get("/login"...)
authRoutes.get("/register"...)
```